# Sails.js upload image is not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to upload an image and get the name of image into MySQL. But i'm still stuck on uploading an image. I'm always get results "files(s) uploaded successfully"

This is controller.

```
upload: function(req, res){
    var picture_path = req.param('picture_path');

    req.file('image').upload({maxBytes: 1000000, dirname : '/assets/pic_items'},function whenDone(err, uploadedFiled){
        if (err) {
            return res.negotiate(err);
        }   
            console.log(uploadedFiled);
            return res.json({
                message: uploadedFiled.length + ' files(s) uploaded successfully'
            });
        if (uploadedFiled.length === 0){
            return res.badRequest('no file was uploaded');
        }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question I am going to assume a couple of things.

1. You have successfully added a MySQL Connection to the connections.js file in your config directory.
2. You have generated a model and controller called 'gallery', which represents a table in your MySQL database also called 'gallery' and your model is successfully created as a representation of the fields in this table.
3. In the gallery table/model you have a field called 'image_name' to store the name of the image and also a field called 'image_uid' which will store a unique identifier (file descriptor).

So now you should have a Gallery model that looks something like this:

```
/**
 * Gallery.js
 *
 * @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it represents here.
 * @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/models
 */

module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    // Anything else you want to capture in your DB
    image_name : {
      type : 'string'
    },

    image_uid : {
      type: 'string'
    },
  }
};
```

In the GalleryController, create an upload function/route to handle the image upload and database insert. This should look like:

```
upload: function(req, res, next) {
    var params = req.params.all();
    console.log(params);

    req.file('fileToUpload').upload({
        // don't allow the total upload size to exceed ~10MB
        dirname: '../../assets/images/gallery',
        maxBytes: 10000000
    },function (err, uploadedFile) {
        if (err) {
            return res.serverError(err); 
        }

        // If no files were uploaded, respond with an error.
        if (uploadedFile.length === 0){
            return res.serverError("No files were uploaded!"); 
        }

        // Use this log all the uploaded file info
        // console.log(uploadedFile[0]);

        // Get the name of the file
        var fileName = uploadedFile[0].filename;
        // Get the file descriptor and remove the directory details
        var fileUID = uploadedFile[0].fd.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

        // Create a galleryItem to insert into database
        var galleryItem = {};
        galleryItem.image_name = fileName;
        galleryItem.image_uid = fileUID;

        // Create the image in your Database
        Gallery.create(galleryItem, function (err, gallery) {
            if(err) {
                return res.serverError('An error occured while adding Image in the DB');
            }

            // return whatever or wherever you want
            return res.redirect("/gallery/");
        });
    });
},
```

Finally, on the clientside you should ensure your form capture is using multipart encoding and the input name matches the 'req.file("fileToUpload")' parameter in your controller. Here is a very basic example:

```
<form action="/gallery/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Displaying the image is as simple as reading the gallery item from the database and passing the image_uid to an image tag.

```
<img src="/images/gallery/<%= gallery.image_uid %>" alt="<%= gallery.image_name %>" >
```

Comment: I'm a lot more understanding now. But I still can't upload image. I always get [] this result.

Comment: Can you extend your code to include both the clientside upload form and the updated upload controller please?